# Can a company disallow taking annual leave during a notice period?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I have just resigned from my current company and I briefly mentioned I have unused annual leave left to take.

They have told me, it is company policy to pay leaving employees for unused annual leave, and thus their preferred option is that I do not take my remaining annual leave.

Is this enforceable in the United Kingdom by law?

My employment contract doesn't specifically say that.

Comment: A company can't force you not to, but they can say you're not allowed to. Very different things.

Answer (score 3):

Annual leave can generally only be taken with the agreement of the employer so, yes its legal.

Comment: Can't speak definitively for UK law,  but I know for a fact that this is the case in New Zealand.